# Google sheets - eliminating common elements from two ranges

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, countif

I am trying to make an assignment system for a project I'm doing. I have two google forms linked up to my spreadsheet, and thus I have three separate sheets: Start, Finish, and Sheet1. Sheet1 is where I want the active assignments to show, and Start and Finish are where the results from the google forms go. Each assignment has three columns: Username, item, and quantity. The specifics of an assignment that someone starts are in Start, and the specifics of an assignment that someone finishes are listed in Finish.

Let's say I have the following data in Start:

| Username | Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Apple | 3 |
| 12345 | Apple | 3 |
| 54321 | Orange | 2 |
| 12345 | Orange | 4 |

And the following data in Finish:

| Username | Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Apple | 3 |
| 12345 | Orange | 4 |

Then, I want Sheet1 to show the following:

| Username | Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Apple | 3 |
| 54321 | Orange | 2 |

Basically, it takes pairs of matching rows and eliminates them. Then, it takes whatever remains in Start and shows them in Sheet1. Is there any function that I can put in Sheet1 that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(FILTER(
          A3:A&"×"&B3:B&"×"&C3:C&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(A3:A&"×"&B3:B&"×"&C3:C, 
          A3:A&"×"&B3:B&"×"&C3:C, ROW(A3:A), "<="&ROW(A3:A)), NOT(COUNTIF(
          E3:E&"×"&F3:F&"×"&G3:G&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(E3:E&"×"&F3:F&"×"&G3:G, 
          E3:E&"×"&F3:F&"×"&G3:G, ROW(E3:E), "<="&ROW(E3:E)),
          A3:A&"×"&B3:B&"×"&C3:C&"×"&
 COUNTIFS(A3:A&"×"&B3:B&"×"&C3:C, 
          A3:A&"×"&B3:B&"×"&C3:C, ROW(A3:A), "<="&ROW(A3:A))))), "×"), 9^9, 3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works as intended. The only thing is that if the finish array has an entry that start does not have, it gives a number and if both arrays are empty then it gives 101. However, both cases shouldn't happen under normal operation.